# How to get email as response in alexa skills

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, alexa-slot

How do I take email as input from Alexa skills? I have the following code to get email input then send the email but I need to understand how to take valid email as input, if I type in *test@gmail.com*, somehow Alexa returns *test gmail.com* to my lambda function. Any help will be appreciated.

*Below is my code:*

```
// sets up dependencies
const Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
const i18n = require('i18next');
const languageStrings = require('./languageStrings');
const requester = require('./util');

const SendMailHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;

   // var code = this.event.request.intent.slots.code.value;
   // console.log(code)

    // checks request type
    return request.type === 'LaunchRequest'
      || (request.type === 'IntentRequest'
        && request.intent.name === 'SendMailIntent');
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = 'Welcome, give me the email details'
    const request = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request;


if(request.intent && request.intent.slots) {
    const receiver = request.intent.slots.ReceiverEmail.value;


        const messageData = {
              "receiverEmail": receiver
        }

        const res = await requester.httpPost(messageData, accessToken);

        console.log(res);
}


    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .getResponse();
  },
};

// Took out default Alexa skills code.

const skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom();

exports.handler = skillBuilder
  .addRequestHandlers(
    SendMailHandler
  )
  .addRequestInterceptors(LocalizationInterceptor)
  .addErrorHandlers(ErrorHandler)
  .lambda();
```

Comment: What type does your slot have?

Comment: The type for the email slot is Search query

Comment: It's not easy to catch an email with voice. You could try to divide the input with two dialogs, one for the user and one for the domain

Answer (score 0):

Since asking user to tell her email is so error prone, you can just use the email provided in the Customer Contact Information. It's well described in the [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html).